# Terran eclipse?

Tags: solar-eclipse, lunar-eclipse

Solar and lunar eclipses are pretty straightforward. But what about eclipses when you are standing on the Moon? I have been trying to Google the info, but there's some gaming clan that has taken the name "terran eclipse" so it's hard to find the real stuff.

I was able to find [this article](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/2009/02/19/what-does-a-lunar-eclipse-look-like-from-the-moon/#.V_eysuArJEY) on lunar eclipse from the Moon (the Earth eclipsing the sun). But what about the other way - a solar eclipse observed from the Moon? What would Earth look like? Would anything special be happening on the Moon?

Comment: A "terran eclipse" is just a lunar eclipse, observed from the Moon.

Comment: Trivia: a total lunar eclipse occurred shortly after Apollo 15. (The astronauts had already left.) [The mission report](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a15/a15mr-4.htm) states the equipment left there recorded a temperature swing of 283 degrees F (140 degrees C) So expect it to get cold...

Comment: Not an answer, but a helpful piece of Google advice.  You can tell Google to omit results with certain words by adding a '-' in front of them.  If you search "terran eclipse -game -community", it gets rid of most of that stuff and the results contain more eclipse from the moon results.  It doesn't get rid of all of it, but with a few more terms ignored you can boil it down to just what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

As Wayfaring Stranger's answer says, during a lunar eclipse seen from Earth, an observer on the Moon would see a solar eclipse. Earth is about 4 times the apparent diameter of the Sun. You can see a photo of such an eclipse, taken by Japan's Kaguya spacecraft in lunar orbit, [here](http://www.universetoday.com/25929/kaguya-captures-eclipse-from-the-moon/).

[image]

During a solar eclipse seen from Earth, an observer on the Moon would see the Moon's shadow on the surface of Earth. I don't know of any photos of such a shadow as seen from the Moon, but here's a photo of a solar eclipse seen from the Mir space station in 1999.

[image: Looking Back at an Eclipsed Earth]

https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap110102.html

Comment: @Pavel Just to note, as seen in the bottom photo, the moon's shadow on Earth (during solar eclipse) is *much* smaller than the Earth's shadow upon the moon during lunar eclipses. In fact "terran eclipse" might be a misnomer -- the Earth can never be totally "shadowed" by the moon.

Comment: `+1` also asked and answered in Space SE: [Have there been any photos taken of a total Earth-Sun eclipse from the Moon, or its vicinity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12116/12102)

Answer (score 4):

A lunar eclipse on earth is a solar eclipse on the moon.
The earth takes up 2° of sky from the lunar surface (vs 0.5°), so you'd see less corona in your space suit. The moon's speed through earth's shadow is only about 1 km per second, so you'd have [up to 107 minutes of totality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_eclipse). What with earth's atmosphere, I doubt you'd see much in the way of [Baily's beads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baily%27s_beads), but there'd likely be a spectacular round the world sunset glow to make up for that.